# Rspec routing test fails for wildcard routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, routes, rspec-rails

**spec/routing/user_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
    it 'should route properly' do
        expect(get: '/users').to route_to(controller: 'users', action: 'index')
        expect(get: '/foo/bar').to route_to(controller: 'users', action: 'index')

    end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :users

match '*path', to: "users#index", via: :get
```

When I hit this url using my browser, this part works perfectly.

**log**

```
Started GET "/foo/bar" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-12 13:42:39 +0530
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"path"=>"foo/bar"}
  User Load (34.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (51.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 261ms (Views: 222.4ms | ActiveRecord: 36.8ms)
```

but when I run my tests using:

```
rspec spec/routing/user_spec.rb
```

It fails with the following **error**

```
Failure/Error: expect(get: '/foo/bar').to route_to(controller: 'users', action: 'index')
       The recognized options <{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"index", "path"=>"foo/bar"}> did not match <{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"index"}>, difference:.
       --- expected
       +++ actual
       @@ -1 +1 @@
       -{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"index"}
       +{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"index", "path"=>"foo/bar"}
     # ./spec/routing/user_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I rectify this to make the tests pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails assigns the part of the path (`'foo/bar'`) that matches the wildcard segment (`*path`) to a request parameter with the same name as the segment, so the action can see how the client got there.

You just need to add the parameter to the result that your test expects:

```
describe UserController do
  describe 'wildcard route'
    it "routes to users#index with path set to the requested path" do
      expect(get: '/foo/bar').to route_to(
        controller: 'users', action: 'index', path: 'foo/bar')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, understood that after taking a real look at the logs and the error message. Plus the result of `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path("/foo/bar", method: "GET")` in the console gives me the same result. So, I will have to test is against a parameter named `path` along with `controller` and `action`.